# Cycle Combined bake without AO

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I have my material setup in blender and want to bake a combined texture (so it includes lighting) but want to bake my AO separately so that the texture can be changed later without blender and the AO applied to it. I tried disabling AO and a few different combined settings but short of pulling my mesh apart (or to different layers) to prevent the AO to be showing, nothing is working.

If I bake combined (tried all type of combinations disabling AO in bake settings and in world tab) I get this which looks great but I don't want the AO (everything but AO):

[image]

Only cheat I found was to explode my mesh (or split to different layers) to lower AO like this:

[image]

As you can see, the AO isn't showing as much (easier to see on the chain) but I would like it all removed.

Is there any way to prevent any AO to be baked onto the combined image?

Comment: Disabling Ambient Occlusion is enough to get rid of it. That said, if you are baking the "lighting" too, it's normal that some of your parts start to show conctact shadows that may resamble to AO (one above all are diffuse shaders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trying the wrong things, I figured my glossy shader node was the one casting the AO, so I disabled Glossy in the Object properties tab, down in Cycles Settings / Ray Visibility.

Now baking combined bakes with light effect but no AO.